# Updating Properties and ping-pong event

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

in a WPF application that uses Catel for MVVM Framework I've got  3 diffetrent properties in a viewmodel

```
    public double? QtaDiv1 { get; set; }

    public double? Exchange{ get; set; }

    public double? QtaDiv2 { get; set; }
```

I've overriden the OnPropertyChanged as

```
protected async override void OnPropertyChanged(AdvancedPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Data")
        {
            await GetValueDate(e);
        }
        else if (e.PropertyName == "QtaDiv1" || e.PropertyName == "Exchange")
        {
            ChangeQtaDiv2(QtaDiv1, Exchange);
        }
        if (e.PropertyName == "QtaDiv2")
        {
            ChangeQtaDiv1(QtaDiv2, Exchange);
        }
        else if (e.PropertyName == "SelectedCross")
        {
            await GetValueDate(e);
            CheckForSplitVisibility();
        }

        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
    }
```

And what  I do is if QtaDiv1 and Exchangehave values I calculate QtaDiv2
Otherwise if QtaDiv2 is changed by the user (and Exchange) I update QtaDiv1.

This works fine till I update QtaDiv2, since at this point I got a PropertyChanged on QtaDiv1 that calls the update on QtaDiv2 and so on...

How can I break this spell??? I thought of setting a string field that holds the changing value but If I do so I've to suppress the RaisePropertyChanged notification (and I've to convert to backing field property) so I won't get the Validation on them

Thanks

Comment: Tip: consider using if (e.HasPropertyChanged(() => Data). It's a bit slower than string comparison, but will be checked at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a simple `bool` variable to signify whether the change came from inside the code, or not:

```
private bool isInternalChange = false;
```

If it is an internal change, then you can ignore it:

```
if (!isInternalChange)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Data")
    {
        await GetValueDate(e);
    }
    else if (e.PropertyName == "QtaDiv1" || e.PropertyName == "Exchange")
    {
        isInternalChange = true;
        ChangeQtaDiv2(QtaDiv1, Exchange);
        isInternalChange = false;
    }
    if (e.PropertyName == "QtaDiv2")
    {
        isInternalChange = true;
        ChangeQtaDiv1(QtaDiv2, Exchange);
        isInternalChange = false;
    }
    else if (e.PropertyName == "SelectedCross")
    {
        await GetValueDate(e);
        CheckForSplitVisibility();
    }

    base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
}
```

Comment: A common construct is a `try..finally`, in case `ChangeQtaDiv` throws.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Sheridan is correct. As @Boris B. points out, it's best to put this into a try...finally. You can do it like this when using Catel:

```
if (!_isInternalChange)
{
    if (e.HasPropertyChanged(() => Data))
    {
        await GetValueDate(e);
    }
    else if (e.HasPropertyChanged(() => QtaDiv1) || e.HasPropertyChanged(() => Exchange))
    {
        using (StartInternalChange())
        {
            ChangeQtaDiv2(QtaDiv1, Exchange);
        }
    }
    if (e.HasPropertyChanged(() => QtaDiv2))
    {
        using (StartInternalChange())
        {   
            ChangeQtaDiv1(QtaDiv2, Exchange);
        }
    }
    else if (e.HasPropertyChanged(() => SelectedCross))
    {
        await GetValueDate(e);
        CheckForSplitVisibility();
    }

    base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
}

private IDisposable StartInternalChange()
{
    return new DisposableToken<MyClass>(this, 
        x => x._isInternalUpdate = false,
        x => x._isInternalUpdate = true);
}
```